# Jest Typescript baseUrl absolute paths, ReferenceError: Main is not defined

Tags: typescript, jestjs, frontend

I try to add Jest to my project (using typescript). Absolute paths are used everywhere (that is, there is no import). Everything seems to be set up correctly, the module with the test sees the files, but when I try to start it writes **ReferenceError: Main is not defined**

**Main.spec.ts:**

```
beforeAll(() => {
    const main = new Main(null, null);
    console.log(main);
});

test("test", () => {
    // // var login: Login = new Login(null, null);
    // var cont: Controller = new Controller(null, null);

    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

**jest.config.ts:**

```
const { defaults } = require('jest-config');

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '../js']
};
```

tsconfig:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "../js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
},
"include": ["./**/*.ts"],
"exclude": ["./__test__"],
"ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es2017"
    }
}
```

}

Error text:

```
ReferenceError: Main is not defined
      1 |
      2 | beforeAll(() => {
    > 3 |       const main = new Main(null, null);
        |                    ^
      4 |       console.log(main);
      5 | });
      6 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/Main.spec.ts:3:15)
```

Comment: Please, update your snippets to include the import statements.

Comment: I don't use imports